# Xcode storyboard showing constraints for all the children

Tags: ios, xcode

I think this is happening since Xcode 11, since in the past years I haven't noticed any kind of problem.

When I click a view in the storyboard and open the constraint panel, all the constraints from the selected view to the parent and from the children to the selected view are displayed, making it a mess to find the constraint you are looking for. In my case, I always click in a view because I need to change the constraints related with the parent. If I need to change some children constraint I go to the children view.

For example, seeing this in the storyboard doesn't help me at all:

[image]

Is there a way to make the storyboard show only the constraints related with the parent? Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand the new layout. Like you said, it's confusing to have literally dozens of constraints for the entire view, including subviews. Did you ever find an answer to just showing parent vs. child constraints?